# Connect time(ms) in jmeter is coming out to be 0

Tags: jmeter, performance

I have a Jmeter plan which has couple of samples.

While running only the first time the **connec time** is non-zero positive number otherwise it is coming out to be 0 for all the other samples

the script is a recorded one.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check keep-alive settings of your samplers. With keep-alive turned on for all samplers each thread would establish connection only once, at the start of test, and reuse it for other requests.

Answer (score 2):

This value of connection time and keep-alive setting, is more usable when application is running on SSL handshake. If this setting is on and once the connection has been established, response times will decrease. Connection time value is important to know if the changes in response times you’re seeing are caused by these connections being established or if they are due to a resource being exhausted.

Earlier versions of JMeter doesn't show Connection time as a separate parameter, the latency in JMeter includes the connection time. So you’ll need to subtract the connect time from latency to get pure latency value.